# Socket between C# server and C# client

Tags: c#, sockets, android-wear-2.0

I'm going to create a socket to send a string from console application server to AndroidWearable client. I use Visual Studio Xamarin, and I never use XML Language. When I click the button nothing happens, How can I improve my program?

```
Part MainActivity.cs

using Android.App;

using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Wearable.Activity;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;





namespace AndroidClient
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : WearableActivity
    {
        private TextView textView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
            SetAmbientEnabled();


        }

        /** Called when the user touches the button */



            // Incoming data from the client.  
        public static string data = null;


        public static void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.  
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
            // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the   
            // host running the application.  
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
             SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and   
            // listen for incoming connections.  
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);

                // Start listening for connections.  
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.  
                    Socket handler = listener.Accept();

                    data = null;

                    // An incoming connection needs to be processed.  
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                        if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Show the data on the console.  
                    Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);




                    // Echo the data back to the client.  
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    handler.Send(msg);
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }



        public void mainsendMessage(View view)
        {
            // Do something in response to button click
            StartListening();
        }
    }

}



Part AXML-Origin


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />


Server C#

    SERVER
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace Server_microsoft
{
    public class SynchronousSocketListener
    {

        // Incoming data from the client.  
        public static string data = null;

        public static void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.  
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
            // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the   
            // host running the application.  
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and   
            // listen for incoming connections.  
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);

                // Start listening for connections.  
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.  
                    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                    data = null;

                    // An incoming connection needs to be processed.  
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                        if (data.IndexOf(data) > -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }    



                        // Show the data on the console.  
                         Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);
                        // Echo the data back to the client.  
                        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        handler.Send(msg);
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();





                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static int Main(String[] args)
        {
            StartListening();
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

For example I have to inser some TextView o see the string? How can I make this or one button is necessary?

Comment: Generally it's best not to post the entire app.  Have you tried running it in a debugger and stepping through the code?  Breakpoints?  Good luck

Comment: Sorry we can help on specific problem. You need to investigate and debug your code.